# Converting a HttpListener to run in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, azure, httplistener

I've heard that there are ways to take a C# app that uses HttpListener and change it such that it will run in IIS but I'm unable to find any concrete references on this.  Does anyone have any ideas on the topic that they could share?

Comment: HAve you tried anything so far?

Comment: Nope - don't even know where to start :-/

Comment: How's that related to the Azure platform ?

Comment: Azure PaaS apps run in IIS.  I'd like to do the same with this one, but it's using HttpListener.  From what I gather there is some way to do this.

Comment: Anyone have any idea?  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found what I was looking for here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001

Looks like there are only minor code changes that would need to be implemented.  Hope this can help someone else, too.

## Edit 6/21/19

@Vermin asked if I could find the link, which I could not, but I did find a *really old* code base of mine with some embarassing code that may at least provide some starting points/directions (hopefully for others too).  Please forgive me if I don't provide good clarity on the 'why' behind some of these items (it was a while ago, and I didn't understand it all to the depth I should have).

1) The ServiceContract

```
[ServiceContract] public interface <svcName> ... 
{
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/*", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        Stream MyGetMethod();

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/*", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        Stream MyPostMethod(Stream bodyStream);
```

2) I also had to provide a content mapper (I can't really remember why)

```
    public class RawContentTypeMapper : WebContentTypeMapper
    {
        public override WebContentFormat GetMessageFormatForContentType(string contentType)
        {
            return WebContentFormat.Raw;
        }
    }
```

3) Then there was something I needed to do in web.config...

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="<namespace>.<svcName>" behaviorConfiguration="<behaviorName>">
        <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" behaviorConfiguration="<behaviorName>" contract="<namespace>.<svcName>" bindingConfiguration="<customBinding>"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="<customBinding>">
          <!-- Used for REST.  See http://www.codehosting.net/blog/BlogEngine/post/WebContentFormatRaw-in-your-WCF-config-file.aspx -->
          <!-- Provide the fully qualified name of the WebContentTypeMapper, set max message size to 500MB  -->
          <webMessageEncoding webContentTypeMapperType="<namespace>.RawContentTypeMapper, <namespace>, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <httpTransport manualAddressing="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="524288000" transferMode="Buffered" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="<behaviorName>">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="<behaviorName>">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <diagnostics performanceCounters="All"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I also saw this link in the comments of the project, which may prove useful: http://www.codehosting.net/blog/BlogEngine/post/WebContentFormatRaw-in-your-WCF-config-file

You'll have to forgive me if I can't really explain the 'why' of all of the above.  Some of it is easy to understand (mapping the GET, POST methods), some of it I felt like I was just trying things (the web.config stuff).

For some context, I recall the app I was migrating had code to deal with all of the underlying HTTP connections and such, and once I migrated it to IIS using the above, it wasn't that it was terribly fragile, I just felt as though I lost a lot of control without actually understanding the how or the why, and needing to make changes *did* cause me to feel it was fragile.  It's one of the reasons I built Watson Webserver (shameless plug) for quickly building RESTful servers: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Watson/2.0.5

Comment: Hi there - this is something that I am looking into right now but it appears that the link you have posted is no longer valid! Are you able to provide an alternative link that can point me in the right direction??

Comment: Hi @Vermin I can't seem to find it any longer.  However, I do recall it required mapping my own methods back to WebGet and WebInvoke using OperationContract within a ServiceContract.  I have some horribly embarassing old source code I could share if you'd like to direct message me.

Comment: Edited to add more context for @Vermin

Answer (score 1):

Is it compiled as an exe you can start on the command line? If so:

Azure projects have a hook you can use to start 3rd party applications that need to run in the background. I suggest you create a Worker Role, add an endpoint to open the necessary port in Azure. Add your existing executable as an item in the project (setting it to copy local), and start it with a background task in the service definition file.

Steve Marx has a good blog post on how to do this here: http://blog.smarx.com/posts/using-other-web-servers-on-windows-azure

Comment: Thanks - yes it is compiled as an EXE but I want to run it within IIS (much like I could with a WCF service etc).  From what I gather there is a way to do this using generic handlers but I can't seem to find an example.

Comment: You say you want it to run within IIS, but is there any particular reason?

Comment: The reasoning is irrelevant.  I'm not looking for an alternate solution.  Thanks for any help you can provide on what changes are required to make an HttpListener app run in IIS.